# Can any body tell me what is list file and map file in c?

Tags: c, windows, command, dos, turbo-c

I am **Manoj** again here to ask you my doubts.

I heard that in turbo c when we are doing projects with more than one source file

then we can generate **list file and map file** .

What are they?

what do they contain?

And how to generate them using the commands at MS-DOS command prompt using tcc for turbo c?

How to generate the assembly code for a c file using turbo tcc commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list file normally contains the assembly language code the compiler generated. It may also contain you original source code interspersed with the asm code.

The map file contains all the static symbols (functions, globals, etc.) in your code and their relative addresses. Depending on your linker settings, it may have other information, such as the address of each line of code in your program. If your program crashes, it is possible to determine where the crash occurred using the map file.

Comment: Back in the days, I remember going through map files to know where it crashed.  Keeping released version map file is also part of our releasing process.  But I haven't use for years now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, map files provide the mappings of functions and variables to relative memory locations. Normally they are not very useful for programmers.

To generate them, look at the help file, all information needed should be there.